# Drupal 7: best practices to override a menu?

Tags: drupal

I have a menu defined in Drupal 7. Let's call it "top". This menu is already placed on the region that i want.

The difference is that it will show up as a select element in my drupal theme.

What are the best practices to override this menu?

Other menus will continue to show up normally, i only need to override this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7)?

You should be more specific, as I'm not sure what you actually want to change.